# Dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?) with PCI compliance

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api, pci-compliance

I am getting this error

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?)
```

I know that putting

```
requestPathInvalidCharacters=""
```

in the web config will allow me to do this, but this is not PCI Compliant and it is simply butting a patch over my problem. Is there a way to work around it?

Comment: Avoid using special characters within uri (check parameters). If you don't have the choice, you may disable it only where needed ?

Comment: How can you disable the validation where needed?

Comment: I disabled it where it where I dont need it but i still dont think its compliant with PCI

Answer (score 0):

First of all find out what the request is and why it is dangerous. If you think your client should send the request see if you you can escape the dangerous characters in the request. For example if you have a > in the request. You add a java script to escape your string before submitting it to your server.